# bumped to the homepage by Community

Tags: discussion

I admit that i'm new here, but still i have a question about the "bumping to homepage" that seems to happen regularly with the message "This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed."
Apparently the idea of bumping to the homepage is to have the spotlight on unanswered questions so that they can be answered and closed. What i'm seeing however is that questions of over a year old get bumped, most of the time already answered but with an inactive question-asker who never returned and did not mark an answer. What is the point of still bumping those questions? In my opinion it is fouling the homepage with old inactive questions that will never have an answer marked anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think the criterion is that the question has no upvoted answers, as oppose to no answers at all - the idea being that people who may not have seen the question first time round will review the 0-score answers and either vote/comment/flag as appropriate, or submit their own answer instead.

We do, unfortunately, have quite a lot of questions where the asker has never come back and accepted an answer.  Even if they don't come back, fresh answers can be useful to the community as a whole as they may help other people who have the same or similar problems...

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, Community bumping unanswered questions gives them more exposure/visibility, so:

1. Well-written questions without answers might get answered by someone who hasn't seen the question before.
2. Poor questions, especially those that cannot be answered due to insufficient information can be close-voted.

I do encourage everyone to close-vote questions that were posted and effectively abandoned by users who didn't provide sufficient information or clarification. There is little to gain in having such questions clutter up the main site.

Comment: How can you put a close-vote on a question? Or is it something that only can be done with more reputation? I can flag a question, but the options presented there do not really seem appropriate for inactive questions.

Comment: You need to have at least 500 rep in order to vote to close. See the [Privileges](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) page. Until you acquire that reputation, it should be possible to flag the question and request a moderator to close it.